# Center of mass and moment of inertia

Tags: calculus

Suppose you have a semi-innite rod along the positive x-axis whose mass density is
given by *p*(x). Is it possible to choose *a* in such a way that the center of mass of the part of the
rod from a onwards is located at *a* + L, for any *a*? In other words, is it possible to choose *p* such
that, if you cut the rod somewhere, then, no matter where the cut was made, the innite piece
has its center of mass a distance L from the cut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $M_0$ as the total mass of the semi-infinite rod in its full length ($x = 0$ to $\infty$).

Then the exponential distribution $\displaystyle p(x) = \frac{M_o}L e^{-x/L}$ is has the desired physical property, which is called "memorylessness" in probability (statistics).

Note that the exponent $x/L$ is dimensionless, while the leading factor $M_0 / L$ has the proper physical dimension of mass density (weight per length).

For any partial rod chopped at $x=a$, the remaining mass is
$$M(a) = \int_{x=a}^{\infty}p(x)dx = M_0 \cdot \left(-e^{\frac{-x}L}\right)\Big|_{a}^{\infty} = M_0 e^{\frac{-a}L}$$

The new center of mass is
\begin{align*}
\frac1{ M(a)} \int_{x=a}^{\infty}xp(x)dx &= e^{\frac{a}L} \left[ x \cdot \left(-e^{\frac{-x}L} \right)\Big|_{a}^{\infty} + \int_{x=a}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-x}L}dx \right] \\
&= e^{\frac{a}L} \left[ a e^{\frac{-a}L}  + L\left(-e^{\frac{-x}L} \right)\Big|_{a}^{\infty} \right] \\
&= e^{\frac{a}L} \left[ a e^{\frac{-a}L}  + L e^{\frac{-a}L} \right] = a + L
\end{align*}
as needed.